# Excel - Enormous Vlookup Concatenate required for Minor Procedure

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a lot of excel data spread accross 32 documents in an identical format that list information. The combined total would be over 6 million rows.

I have another document that contains a few thousand rows. The CONCATENTATE of Column C,E and L in this new document could be the same as the CONCATENATE of column D, F and N in any of the other 32 documents.

I want to find information that is the same and grab the hole lot of it for each row in the small document from each of the larger documents.

At the moment this required that I concatenate the info on each of the larger documents, remove all spaces and punctuation and use 32 IFERROR calculation each containing a VLOOKUP. The last one took all night. All others have crashed the computer.

The must be a better way of doing this???

EG.

Small document:

TITLE1   |   TITLE2   |   TITLE3

Larger documents (all 32)

FACT1   | FACT2   |   FACT3   |   TITLE1   |   TITLE2   |   FACT4   |   TITLE3

If the concatenation of Title 1,2 and 3 of the small document finds the same info in any of the concatentations of title 1,2 and 3 (removing all spaces and punctuation) from the larger document. I want to copy in all the information for that row from the larger document including the titles and facts adjacent to the row of info in the smaller document.

Comment: Is the data in each of your 32 files all on a single sheet, or do your files contain multiple sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Ai yai yai. Excel is not made for doing something like this. It's simply the wrong tool. So assuming that you are stuck with that, I would try creating an Access database, linking each spreadsheet you need, then writing a query. I'm not totally clear on what you want to do with the matched info, but you could export it to a new spreadsheet, or link a spreadsheet to that query.

In Access (2007+), go to the External Data tab, click on Excel in the Import section, then select Link. If that is still too slow, you will need to copy the spreadsheets in and perform the query.

Answer (score 1):

Would be much better in a database rather than Excel, 
but to make it work efficiently in Excel you need to use the binary search option (sorted approximate match) of VLOOKUP or MATCH. This is several orders of magnitude faster than linear (unsorted) search: 
1. Create additional columns doing the concatenation etc on the 32 sheets and the small sheet.
2. Sort the data on the 32 sheets using the concatenated column
3. Use a Double VLOOKUP with IF to turn the Approximate match into an exact match, something like this

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(PartNumber,PartsList,1,TRUE)=PartNumber, VLOOKUP(PartNumber,PartsList,4,TRUE), “Missing”)
```

See http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/vlookup-tricks-why-2-vlookups-are-better-than-1-vlookup/
for a more detailed explanation of this formula.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a structure so you know in which sheet you need to search, you could see if the INDIRECT function can help you. Otherwise, I suggest you import the data in a database (such as Access) and then query your data.