# Excel: How to automagically combine Multiple (28) files into One file (worksheet) same columns (13)?

Tags: excel

How to automagically combine Multiple (28) files into
one file (worksheet) same columns (13)?

Comment: How many times times do you need to do it? Once? Often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10109148/120097) to a similar question. Basically, you want to use MS Access for this, not Excel.

Comment: (1) Suggesting another application is not an answer. Plus this is also an incorrect generalisation. There are good reason to use a template based Excel system. (2) Why not flag this as a duplicate rather than link to another question "answered" in this manner?

Comment: @brettdj 1) Well, the OP says nothing about acomplishing this in Excel only, so I just answered with how I would approach this problem. It's something I have done before and I believe Access is the correct answer. 2) I really didn't think about it, it's just something I've seen done hundreds of times here before, but point taken. I've never actually flagged anything as a duplicate and I didn't know I had that ability. Next time I'm tempted to link to an answer, I will take that into consideration.